# Paging toolbar display info not updated during filter operations

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have grid with pagination function while i tried to search data in grid it's been working fine but pagination display info not updated. It's show only info detail of first time loaded

Answer (score -1):

I resolve the above mentioned issue.i thought  It's my mistake, forget to update the total count during filter function.